# jquery focus in / out

Tags: jquery

I would like is to add class "active" to input on input focus, and when focus off, remove that class.

Thank's

Answer (score 46, accepted):

once you've included the jquery lib, it's pretty standard

```
$('input').focus( function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('input').blur( function() {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

focus and blur are more appropriate than focusin and focusout for just input focusing.  focusin and focusout bubble events to children objects and for the most part, that's (likely) unnecessary here.

pretty standard stuff.  take a look at the jquery docs for more.  also maybe modify the selector (the 'input' part) if you only want it for particular input fields.

selector examples:

$('input#my_id_is_bob') for 
$('input.my_class_is_activatable') for

Answer (score 8):

If target-id is the id of the input on which you want to swap the class in and out, you could use something like this:

```
$('#target-id').focusin(  
  function(){  
    $(this).addClass('active');  
  }).focusout(  
  function(){  
    $(this).removeClass('active');  
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#id-of-your-field").focusin(function() {
    $('#id-of-your-field').addClass("active");
});
$("#id-of-your-field").focusout(function() {
    $('#id-of-your-field').removeClass("active");
});
```

This would solve your problem

Comment: This doesn't work for me, maybe is problem in jquery version. 
I have: jquery-1.4.2.min.js

Answer (score 5):

Try the following.

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active");
}).focusOut(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) would look like this:

```
$('input').on("focus", function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
}).on("blur", function() {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

or extra extra short:

```
$('input').on("focus blur", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

alternatives for focus & blur are "focusin" and "focusout" but are bubbling events as Michael Glass pointed out.

> The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, gains focus. This is distinct from the focus event in that it supports detecting the focus event on parent elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `focus` and `blur` functions

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {  
   $(this).addClass("active");  
});  
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {  
    $(this).removeClass("active");  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like `$(this).attr('class','active');` in your `focusin` and `$(this).attr('class','');` in your `focusout`.

Comment: Yes, I putt next code and it doesn't work's:
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 
 $("input").focusin(function() { 
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });

 $("input").focusout(function() { 
  $(this).removeClass('active');
 });


});

Answer (score 0):

Or better try to use this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {  
   $(this).addClass("active");  
}).blur(function() {  
    $(this).removeClass("active");  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

More usefull code if you use input elements, like 'Share forms' and use button 'Send message' or something than does't hide forms :

```
$(function() {
    $("html").click(function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == "your_id_element") { 
            $('#your_id_elements').addClass('open');
        } else if($(e.target).closest('.some_div_without_reaction').length == 0) { 
           if($('#your_id_element').hasClass('open') && $('#your_id_element').val()==''){
                $('#your_id_element').removeClass('open');
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach event handlers using the `.bind()` or better the `.on()` method then check for the `event.type`

```
$(element).bind("focus blur", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
     if(event.type == "focus")
       {
        // Input focused/clicked
        $(element).addClass('active');
       } 

     else if(event.type == "blur")
       {
        // Lost focus
        $(element).removeClass('active');
       }
 });
```