# Simplify jQuery Code on "Focusin / Focusout"

Tags: jquery

I am trying to reduce redundant code on my 'focusin' and 'focusout' code. Essentially, I am adding / removing a class depending on if I am focusing on an input on my web page.

I have already tried using the focus() method instead of the focusin / focusout. I have also tried toggleClass().

```
// On focus, remove the class of reduce and add the class of expand
$('input[type="text"]').on('focusin', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('reduce');
    $(this).addClass('expand');
});

// On focus out, add class reduce and remove class expand
$('input[type="text"]').on('focusout', function () {
    $(this).addClass('reduce');
    $(this).removeClass('expand');
});
```

It works correctly at the moment, but I just want to reduce redundant code.

Comment: which part of this is redundant?

Comment: The code is so similar that's why I consider it being redundant. Is there no way to simplify the code?

Comment: You are doing the opposite in each handler, it looks clean and straight forward. I don't see any reason to refactor it

Comment: you are firing your code on 2 separate events so the only refactor I would do is


$('input[type="text"]').on('focusin', function(){
// On focus, remove the class of reduce and add the class of expand
    $(this).toggleClass('expand reduce');
}).on('focusout', function () {
// On focus out, add class reduce and remove class expand
    $(this).toggleClass('reduce expand');    
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very much shorter, but if you really need to reduce code, this might work for you:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('focusin focusout', function(ev){
    var isFocusIn = ev.type === 'focusin';
    $(this).toggleClass('reduce', !isFocusIn).toggleClass('expand', isFocusIn);
});
```

Comment: A few less lines but to another dev this is harder to read than the original. If you are working in a team I suggest you use your original code. If you are working by yourself, look at this code again in a month or so, if you can't figure out what's going on on first glance, then it is hard to read

Comment: That's a good point. I did not think of the team environment. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I agree that code clarity is useful (independently if you're working in a team or on your own), in this case I probably would have opted for my solution because it's just two functions doing exactly the opposite. Code maintainability gains in this case in my opinion but I guess this is a matter of preferences.

Answer (score 0):

The only "redundant" part right now would be the $(this) part, since you can chain those jQuery calls like below:

```
// On focus, remove the class of reduce and add the class of expand
$('input[type="text"]').on('focusin', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('reduce').addClass('expand');
});

// On focus out, add class reduce and remove class expand
$('input[type="text"]').on('focusout', function () {
    $(this).addClass('reduce').removeClass('expand');
});
```

EDIT: Note that

```
// On focus, remove the class of reduce and add the class of expand
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('reduce').addClass('expand');
});

// On focus out, add class reduce and remove class expand
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function () {
    $(this).addClass('reduce').removeClass('expand');
});
```

Could be a better choice, based on [this selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787114/jquery-focus-in-out), for the bubbling of the event to children nodes, mentioned for the focusin/out direct handlers, instead of jQuerys api .focus/.blur

Answer (score 0):

you are firing your code on 2 separate events so the only refactor I would do is

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('focusin', function(){
// On focus, remove the class of reduce and add the class of expand
    $(this).toggleClass('expand reduce');
}).on('focusout', function () {
// On focus out, add class reduce and remove class expand
    $(this).toggleClass('reduce expand');    
});
```